# Staking multiple columns to two columns and removing duplicates in R

Tags: r

I have multiple columns, but here is only a part of my data:

```
df<-read.table (text=" Color1   Size1   Color2  Size2   Color3  Size3
Yellow  AA  Gray    GB  Purpul  MO
Blue    BD  Cyne    CE  Gray    GB
Yellow  AA  Yellow  AA  Black   LL
Red MD  Reddark KK  Reddark KK
Green   MC  Reddark KK  Green   MC
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to bring down all the columns and show them as two columns and then remove duplicates to get this table:

```
Color   Size
Yellow  AA
Blue    BD
Red MD
Green   MC
Gray    GB
Cyne    CE
Reddark KK
Purpul  MO
Black   LL
```

I try Reshape2 using melt, but I struggled to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of using `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()` can be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate(name=substr(name,1,nchar(name)-1)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% mutate(id2=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  select(-id2) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(paste(Color,Size)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Color   Size 
  <fct>   <fct>
1 Yellow  AA   
2 Gray    GB   
3 Purpul  MO   
4 Blue    BD   
5 Cyne    CE   
6 Black   LL   
7 Red     MD   
8 Reddark KK   
9 Green   MC
```

Comment: @user330 Great question too +1

Answer (score 3):

With no other libraries, reshape and unique can get the job done:

```
> unique(reshape(df, varying=1:6, direction="long", v.names=c("Color", "Size"), timevar=NULL)[1:2])
      Color Size
1.1  Yellow   AA
2.1    Blue   BD
4.1     Red   MD
5.1   Green   MC
1.2    Gray   GB
2.2    Cyne   CE
4.2 Reddark   KK
1.3  Purpul   MO
3.3   Black   LL
```

Pivoting seems like overkill to me, but what do I know. If the index bothers you (though it saves the information on how the wide table was structured) then reset the row names:

```
> uniq = unique(reshape(df, varying=1:6, direction="long", v.names=c("Color", "Size"), timevar=NULL)[1:2])
> rownames(uniq) = NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to reshape from 'wide' to 'long' in two columns by specifying the `names_sep` as the boundary between a letter and a digit (`(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)`) in the column names and then take the `distinct` of the two columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(),
     names_to = c( '.value', 'grp'), names_sep="(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)") %>% 
   distinct(Color, Size)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#  Color   Size 
#  <chr>   <chr>
#1 Yellow  AA   
#2 Gray    GB   
#3 Purpul  MO   
#4 Blue    BD   
#5 Cyne    CE   
#6 Black   LL   
#7 Red     MD   
#8 Reddark KK   
#9 Green   MC
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns('^Color', '^Size'),
       value.name = c('Color', 'Size'))[, variable := NULL])
#     Color Size
#1:  Yellow   AA
#2:    Blue   BD
#3:     Red   MD
#4:   Green   MC
#5:    Gray   GB
#6:    Cyne   CE
#7: Reddark   KK
#8:  Purpul   MO
#9:   Black   LL
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Color1 = c("Yellow", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", 
"Green"), Size1 = c("AA", "BD", "AA", "MD", "MC"), Color2 = c("Gray", 
"Cyne", "Yellow", "Reddark", "Reddark"), Size2 = c("GB", "CE", 
"AA", "KK", "KK"), Color3 = c("Purpul", "Gray", "Black", "Reddark", 
"Green"), Size3 = c("MO", "GB", "LL", "KK", "MC")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Error: `distinct()` must use existing variables

Comment: @user330 Based on the data you showed, it is working correctly for me